# If a method only does something if a condition is true, should I indicate that in the method name?

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

Let's say I have this setup in Ruby on Rails:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
after_create :perform_some_action
#...
private
def perform_some_action
    if some_condition_met?
        #take some action
    end
end
```

Should I add something to the method name, `perform_some_action`, to indicate that it depends on a condition?

Comment: Yes, the best thing would be to have a self explanatory method name

Comment: Another approach is for the condition test to be outside.  So, if some_condition_met then perform_some_action.  Alternatively, if the condition is very tightly-coupled to the action then the condition could be inside the action method and I see no need for the condition to be in the method name.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, yes, because your condition check is **inside** the method.

This way, when calling your method from outside, the code will look self-explanatory. If not, when you read your call it will give you the impression that `take_some_action` is performed whithout any condition.

However, if 37 conditions are required inside your method, perhaps it's the signal that this method should be split up in several smaller ones.